# Sort Algorithm for a set of elements knowing pair order

Tags: algorithm, set

Here is a problem that I'm seeking an algorithmic solution for. Suppose we have a set of n elements, A1, A2, ..., An
And we have a set of rules like A1 > A2, A1 < A3 and etc. Rules are enough for writing the sorted list by hand. Is there a known method for doing the sort? I don't want to do a bubble sort like loop, I'm looking for a standard solution. Any ideas? A name would be enough for me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Arash can u please elaborate whats that mean I'm looking for a standard solution

Comment: @user2864740: Not really. The typical sort algorithms will only work if for every pair `(x, y)` of elements with `x != y`, either `x < y` or `x > y` is known.

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry, but it doesn't mean that. We don't have rules for every possible comparison, we have rule for a subset of possible comparisons which are enough to get the total order.

Comment: @girishlalwani2010 By standard solution I mean a classified method, something like when we say "A* algorithm", or "Quick Sort", or "DLX".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparison-based sort algorithms will only work if you have a [total ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), that is if for every pair `x, y` with `x != y`, we know whether `x < y` or `y < x`. What you have is a [partial ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) on your set of elements and what you are looking for is a [toplogical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the elements according to that partial order.

To find it, interpret your input as a graph with edges `(a, b)` where `a < b` is an input pair. Then do a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on that graph:

```
dfs(x):
  if x is visited: return
  for every rule x < y or y > x:
    dfs(y)
  add x to front of output

output = []
for every element x:
  dfs(x)
```

The runtime is `O(n + m)` where `n` is the number of elements (nodes) and `m` is the number of rules (edges).

Comment: Thanks. I'll be thinking on it while reading other suggestion. This seems to be the only answer so far!

Comment: @Arash: Yeah, comparison-based sort as has been suggested cannot solve this.

Comment: @Arash: Even if there are no loops, you use DFS to get the depth-first forest. It has the property that for every node `x`, all the nodes reachable from that node in the graph are in the subtree of `x`. That's not true for BFS forests. Say you have `A < B, A < D, B < D, B < C`. A valid BFS tree would be `A -> B, A -> D, B -> C`. You have lost the piece of information `B < D` and thus the tree is not sufficient to extract a valid topological order.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and also for this comment.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, take your pick!

- [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
- [Quick Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)
- [Heap Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)

Any comparison sort will work; just put your rules into a big if/else statement in a single function, and the comparison sort will be more than happy to sort them as you like.

Comment: I don't think that's true. Say we have `n` input elements and rules `1 < 2, 2 < 3, ..., n - 1 < n`. The final order is determined completely but the comparison based sorts will make around `n * log n` comparisons, but we only know the result of at most `n` of these. How do we answer the other comparisons?